# Migrate Photos projects to a new Mac

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app, data-transfer

How to migrate Projects from Photos to a new MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

Photos projects are stored in the Photos library, which you can copy to another computer. By default, the Photos library is located in ~/Pictures, i.e. the Pictures folder in your home folder. Copy this to your new computer in the same place, then open the Photos app.